# C - map iterator

Tags: c, dictionary, iterator

I've failed a test (see below) and would like to understand still what could be the answer, could someone help me ?

1 - Give a possible prototype for the map_iterate function below

```
static bool iter_cb(struct pair_t *pair,void *user_data)
{

  struct process_t *process = user_data;

/*

'pair' processing

*/

  return true;

}

int process_data(struct process_t *process, struct map_t *map)

{

  return map_iterate(map, iter_cb, process);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `process_data` returns the result of `map_iterate`, and the return type of `process_data` is `int`, then the return type of `map_iterate` *must* be `int`:

```
int map_iterate( ... );
```

The input parameter `map` is passed straight through to `map_iterate`, and `map` has type `struct map_t *`, so the first parameter to `map_iterate` must have type `struct map_t *`:

```
int map_iterate( struct map_t *, ... );
```

Like `map`, `process` is passed straight through, and has type `struct process_t *`, so the last parameter *must* have type `struct process_t *`:

```
int map_iterate( struct map_t *, ..., struct process_t * );
```

Here's where things get funky. The expression `iter_cb` doesn't *call* the `iter_cb` function; instead, it resolves to a *pointer* to that function, and the type of the expression is `bool (*)(struct pair_t *,void *)` (pointer to function taking pointers to `struct pair_t` and `void` and returning `bool`), so your prototype now looks like

```
int map_iterate( struct map_t *, bool (*)(struct pair_t *, void *), struct process_t * );
```

With (short) identifiers, you get

```
int map_iterate( struct map_t *m, bool (*f)(struct pair_t *, void *), struct process_t *p );
```

Note that `static` is a *storage class specifier*, not a type specifier, so it doesn't play a role in the declaration of the second parameter in the `map_iterator` prototype.  In the declaration/definition of the `iter_cb` function, it only specifies that the function name `iter_cb` not be exported to the linker, meaning the function cannot be called by name outside of the current translation unit (i.e., the current source file).

Answer (score 3):

First and thrid parameters are simple, you can define them based on parameters passed to `process_data` function.

The second one must be a pointer to function, so you need to define that type, with `typedef`, for example:

```
typedef bool (*iterator)(struct pair_t *,void *);

int map_iterate( struct map_t *map, iterator iterator_func, struct process_t *process);
```

or without defining a type you can

```
int map_iterate( struct map_t *map, bool (*iterator)(struct pair_t *,void *), struct process_t *process);
```